# linking pyQt files don't relate

Tags: python-3.x, menu, pyqt5

I have a pyQt script (created with pyuic5 in terminal) that creates a window with some functions. This works and script is below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Main import Ui_Main
from resources.icons import *
import sys


class MainW(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainW, self).__init__(parent)  #pyQt5
        self.ui = Ui_Main()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.setupUi
        self.ui.retranslateUi(self)

        # self.ui.setWindowIcon(QtWidgets.QIcon('MeasLogoSm.png'))
        # self.ui.setWindowTitle("Meas Sound Measurement Tool")

        self.ui.progressBar.setProperty("value", 1)

        # measExit = self.ui.menuJBae_Meas.addAction(self.ui.actionExit)
        # measExit.triggered.connect(self.Exit)


    def Exit(self):
        choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit Meas',
                    "Are You sure to Leave Meas?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainapp = MainW()
    mainapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem raises after this. I want to create some functions. I started with the a quit function in the menu.
I can't get my exit script linked to the script. I think it becomes because the standard file have an object `main` where all sub objects are related to.
I can't figure out how I can relate the my script (Now the upper one) with the standard script from pyuic5 (script below)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Main(object):
    def setupUi(self, Main):
        Main.setObjectName("Main")
        Main.resize(885, 600)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Main.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Main.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Main.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"SansSerif\";")
        self.Central = QtWidgets.QWidget(Main)
        self.Central.setObjectName("Central")
        self.Logo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.Central)
        self.Logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 240, 121))
        self.Logo.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(240, 120))
        self.Logo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 350))
        self.Logo.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedKingdom))
        self.Logo.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Logo.setObjectName("Logo")
        self.test = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.Central)
        self.test.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 520, 80, 23))
        self.test.setObjectName("test")
        self.start = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.Central)
        self.start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 520, 131, 23))
        self.start.setObjectName("start")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Central)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 520, 521, 27))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.layoutWidget)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        self.dateTimeEdit = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.dateTimeEdit.setObjectName("dateTimeEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.dateTimeEdit)
        self.plotTop = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.Central)
        self.plotTop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 10, 521, 240))
        self.plotTop.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 240))
        self.plotTop.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.plotTop.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.plotTop.setObjectName("plotTop")
        self.PlotBottom = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.Central)
        self.PlotBottom.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 260, 521, 240))
        self.PlotBottom.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 240))
        self.PlotBottom.setObjectName("PlotBottom")
        self.layoutWidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Central)
        self.layoutWidget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 10, 28, 231))
        self.layoutWidget1.setObjectName("layoutWidget1")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 180, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.ViewPropTop = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.ViewPropTop.setObjectName("ViewPropTop")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.ViewPropTop)
        self.zoomTop = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.zoomTop.setObjectName("zoomTop")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.zoomTop)
        self.toolTop = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.toolTop.setObjectName("toolTop")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.toolTop)
        self.layoutWidget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Central)
        self.layoutWidget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 260, 28, 231))
        self.layoutWidget2.setObjectName("layoutWidget2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 180, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.ViewPropBBottom = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.layoutWidget2)
        self.ViewPropBBottom.setObjectName("ViewPropBBottom")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.ViewPropBBottom)
        self.ZoomBottom = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.layoutWidget2)
        self.ZoomBottom.setObjectName("ZoomBottom")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.ZoomBottom)
        self.toolBottom = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.layoutWidget2)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../resources/icons/WrenchSm.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
        self.toolBottom.setIcon(icon)
        self.toolBottom.setObjectName("toolBottom")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.toolBottom)
        self.layoutWidget3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.Central)
        self.layoutWidget3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 231, 271))
        self.layoutWidget3.setObjectName("layoutWidget3")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.TypeLab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.TypeLab.setObjectName("TypeLab")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.TypeLab)
        self.TypeSel = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.TypeSel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 0))
        self.TypeSel.setStatusTip("")
        self.TypeSel.setObjectName("TypeSel")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.TypeSel)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Level = QtWidgets.QDial(self.layoutWidget3)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.Level.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.Level.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.Level.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 75))
        self.Level.setStatusTip("")
        self.Level.setAccessibleDescription("")
        self.Level.setObjectName("Level")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.Level, 1, 1, 2, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.lengthLab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.lengthLab.setObjectName("lengthLab")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lengthLab)
        self.length = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.length.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 0))
        self.length.setObjectName("length")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.length)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.itterationsLab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.itterationsLab.setObjectName("itterationsLab")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.itterationsLab)
        self.Itterations = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.Itterations.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 0))
        self.Itterations.setAccessibleDescription("")
        self.Itterations.setObjectName("Itterations")
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.Itterations)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_5, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.startLab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.startLab.setObjectName("startLab")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.startLab, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.startSlid = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.layoutWidget3)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.startSlid.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.startSlid.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.startSlid.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 0))
        self.startSlid.setMaximum(100000)
        self.startSlid.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.startSlid.setObjectName("startSlid")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.startSlid, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.startSpin = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.startSpin.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(65, 0))
        self.startSpin.setDecimals(0)
        self.startSpin.setMaximum(100000.0)
        self.startSpin.setProperty("value", 1.0)
        self.startSpin.setObjectName("startSpin")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.startSpin, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.endLab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.endLab.setObjectName("endLab")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.endLab, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.endSlid = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.layoutWidget3)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.endSlid.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.endSlid.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.endSlid.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 0))
        self.endSlid.setMaximum(100000)
        self.endSlid.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.endSlid.setObjectName("endSlid")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.endSlid, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.endSpin = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.layoutWidget3)
        self.endSpin.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(65, 0))
        self.endSpin.setDecimals(0)
        self.endSpin.setMaximum(100000.0)
        self.endSpin.setProperty("value", 100000.0)
        self.endSpin.setObjectName("endSpin")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.endSpin, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 5, 0, 1, 2)
        self.layoutWidget.raise_()
        self.Logo.raise_()
        self.test.raise_()
        self.start.raise_()
        self.plotTop.raise_()
        self.layoutWidget.raise_()
        self.PlotBottom.raise_()
        self.layoutWidget.raise_()
        self.layoutWidget.raise_()
        Main.setCentralWidget(self.Central)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Main)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 885, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuJBae_Meas = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuJBae_Meas.setObjectName("menuJBae_Meas")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        Main.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Main)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Main.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(Main)
        self.actionExit.setEnabled(True)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(Main)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionSave_All = QtWidgets.QAction(Main)
        self.actionSave_All.setObjectName("actionSave_All")
        self.actionPreferences = QtWidgets.QAction(Main)
        self.actionPreferences.setObjectName("actionPreferences")
        self.actionSave_As = QtWidgets.QAction(Main)
        self.actionSave_As.setObjectName("actionSave_As")
        self.actionDelete_Measurement = QtWidgets.QAction(Main)
        self.actionDelete_Measurement.setObjectName("actionDelete_Measurement")
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(Main)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(Main)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
        self.menuJBae_Meas.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuJBae_Meas.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuJBae_Meas.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuJBae_Meas.addAction(self.actionSave_As)
        self.menuJBae_Meas.addAction(self.actionSave_All)
        self.menuJBae_Meas.addSeparator()
        self.menuJBae_Meas.addAction(self.actionPreferences)
        self.menuJBae_Meas.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionDelete_Measurement)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuJBae_Meas.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(Main)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Main)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.TypeSel, self.length)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.length, self.Itterations)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.Itterations, self.startSlid)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.startSlid, self.startSpin)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.startSpin, self.endSlid)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.endSlid, self.endSpin)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.endSpin, self.Level)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.Level, self.start)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.start, self.test)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.test, self.ViewPropTop)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.ViewPropTop, self.zoomTop)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.zoomTop, self.toolTop)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.toolTop, self.ViewPropBBottom)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.ViewPropBBottom, self.ZoomBottom)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.ZoomBottom, self.toolBottom)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.toolBottom, self.plotTop)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.plotTop, self.PlotBottom)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.PlotBottom, self.dateTimeEdit)
        Main.setTabOrder(self.dateTimeEdit, self.Logo)

    def retranslateUi(self, Main):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Main.setWindowTitle(_translate("Main", "Main"))
        self.test.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Open Menu Test Signal"))
        self.test.setText(_translate("Main", "Test"))
        self.start.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Start Measurement"))
        self.start.setText(_translate("Main", "Start"))
        self.ViewPropTop.setText(_translate("Main", "..."))
        self.zoomTop.setText(_translate("Main", "..."))
        self.toolTop.setText(_translate("Main", "..."))
        self.ViewPropBBottom.setText(_translate("Main", "..."))
        self.ZoomBottom.setText(_translate("Main", "..."))
        self.toolBottom.setText(_translate("Main", "..."))
        self.TypeLab.setText(_translate("Main", "Type"))
        self.TypeSel.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Select Signal Type"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Main", "Level"))
        self.Level.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Set Volume Level"))
        self.lengthLab.setText(_translate("Main", "Length"))
        self.length.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Select Length of Signal in k samples"))
        self.itterationsLab.setText(_translate("Main", "Itterations"))
        self.Itterations.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Select number of itterations"))
        self.startLab.setText(_translate("Main", "Start"))
        self.startSlid.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Select Start Frequency"))
        self.startSpin.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Set Start Frequency"))
        self.endLab.setText(_translate("Main", "End"))
        self.endSlid.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Select End Frequency"))
        self.endSpin.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Set End Frequency"))
        self.menuJBae_Meas.setTitle(_translate("Main", "&File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("Main", "Edit"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("Main", "&Quit"))
        self.actionExit.setIconText(_translate("Main", "Quit"))
        self.actionExit.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Exit Meas"))
        self.actionExit.setShortcut(_translate("Main", "Ctrl+Q"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("Main", "&Save"))
        self.actionSave.setIconText(_translate("Main", "&Save"))
        self.actionSave.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Save Measurements"))
        self.actionSave.setShortcut(_translate("Main", "Ctrl+S"))
        self.actionSave_All.setText(_translate("Main", "Save All"))
        self.actionSave_All.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Save All Measurements"))
        self.actionSave_All.setShortcut(_translate("Main", "Ctrl+Shift+S"))
        self.actionPreferences.setText(_translate("Main", "&Preferences"))
        self.actionPreferences.setIconText(_translate("Main", "&Preferences"))
        self.actionPreferences.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Preferences Meas"))
        self.actionPreferences.setShortcut(_translate("Main", "Ctrl+I"))
        self.actionSave_As.setText(_translate("Main", "Save As"))
        self.actionSave_As.setToolTip(_translate("Main", "Save Measurements As"))
        self.actionDelete_Measurement.setText(_translate("Main", "Delete Measurement"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("Main", "&Open"))
        self.actionOpen.setIconText(_translate("Main", "&Open"))
        self.actionOpen.setShortcut(_translate("Main", "Ctrl+O"))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("Main", "&New"))
        self.actionNew.setIconText(_translate("Main", "&New"))
        self.actionNew.setShortcut(_translate("Main", "Ctrl+N"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Main()
    ui.setupUi(Main)
    Main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How get I this second script can use the objects from `main` ?

Comment: The code in your question is not valid python code - it has syntax errors, and sections have been removed. Always make sure you post **all** the code necessary to reproduce your problem, and make sure it runs properly.

Comment: Now it should be valid code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the widgets added in Qt Designer become attributes of the object assigned to `self.ui`, which is just a simple namespace. So you can access `actionExit` and connect it to a slot, like this:

```
class MainW(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainW, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Main()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # self.ui.setWindowIcon(QtWidgets.QIcon('MeasLogoSm.png'))
        # self.ui.setWindowTitle("Meas Sound Measurement Tool")

        self.ui.progressBar.setProperty("value", 1)

        self.ui.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.Exit)
```

But note that the `Exit` method has some errors, and should instead look like this:

```
    def Exit(self):
        choice = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit Meas',
                    "Are You sure to Leave Meas?",
                    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.close()
```

If you want to avoid having to type `self.ui` all the time, you can simplify things a bit by using the multi-inheritance approach:

```
class MainW(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Main):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainW, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # self.setWindowIcon(QtWidgets.QIcon('MeasLogoSm.png'))
        # self.setWindowTitle("Meas Sound Measurement Tool")

        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 1)

        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.Exit)
```

Now all the widgets added in Qt Designer are direct attributes of the `MainW` object.

Comment: Can you explain why `self.close()` is better than `sys.exit()`?

Comment: In pyqt, its just more idiomatic to start the application with `sys.exit(app.exec_())`, and then stop it with `close()` or `quit()`. But the real errors in your `Exit` method were that you were using `QtGui`, rather than `QtWidgets`.

Comment: Check now i see what you did.. missed that the first time!!